# How do I refer to an entity from which some other entity depends on?

Tags: word-choice

So I have A and B.
B depends on A, which is why B is a dependent entity or a dependant.
In this case what do I call the A entity? A defining entity?
What is the right way to express that it is something which something else depends on?

**UPDATE:**

I apologize for not mentioning the lack of any specific context which people are asking about. Well, it is so very abstract and there is simply ***no context*** defined at all. All we know is that A only ***exerts some influence*** over B making it dependent. Let me be even more precise, all we known is that the existence of B doesn't make sense if A doesn't exist.

I cannot accept following alternatives, because they imply some context which we don't have and thus can be misleading:

- provider (A provides something to B), sorry, nothing is being provided
- controller (A controls B), sorry, no controlling is involved
- parent/child relation (A is a parent of B), sorry, no inheritance is involved

There were "precedent" and "antecedent" which imply a cause/outcome relation between things. They are pretty abstract and seem like almost what I was looking for except for the unwanted time substance being involved.

I really like the [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7087/354) from StoneyB who suggested "governing" or "determining". Out of all I think *determining* works the best in a very abstract sense of the matter in question.

Also it was brought up that there is a similar question at EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36033/if-a-person-depends-upon-you-what-are-you-for-him

Comment: It probably "depends" on context. If B is, say, a child or otherwise dependent/dependant, A is probably a *parent* or *carer*. If B is a "software construct", A may be a *parent* if B is created from it by "inheritance", or perhaps a *prerequisite* if not. Other words may be more suitable in other contexts, so until you've given more detail I don't see how this can be answered succinctly.

Comment: So you are saying there is no general purpose word (adjective) that conveys the matter in question as well as "dependent" does for a dependent entity, aren't you? Basically what I need is to label the other party of a dependency relation somehow without going into details of the nature of that dependency.

Comment: @ bonomo: I *think* I'm saying that there isn't really any "general-purpose" context for such a word. I depend on air, for example. Getting an answer on ELL depends on framing a meaningful question. A derived software class depends on its parent. A disabled person often depends on a family member for "living assistance". These are all quite different relationships - the fact that I can use the word "depend" in every case doesn't imply there should be a generic word for "thing/person depended upon". What is *your* context?

Comment: bonomo, I *think* a general term can be *antecedent*. In fact MW says "4 a : a preceding event, condition, *or cause*". Therefore if A causes B, this implies B depends on A.

Comment: ... but FF is somewhat right. In fact, with more context, it may exist a more specialized word.

Comment: ... and, reminding some previous questions about the prefix "para", we could say that, in your case, "antecedent", is a *paraword*-i.e. a word with the parachute.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, well that's the problem, my domain is too general to define the context. There is no context or a void context or very general context, if you will. So what I am asking is what I really mean, I wish there was a universal adjective to label a counterpart of a dependent entity. By design the nature of the dependency doesn't matter at this point and will be specified later by different people. I am asking to because I am having a hard time giving a name to property of the "Dependency" class that already has the "DependentEntity" property.

Comment: bonomo, do you agree that "antecedent" can be the right word? Since you are still replying to the obsolete FF's comments, I'm under the impression that my previous comments are transparent to your eyes.

Comment: @Carlo_R, "antecedent" looks like being somewhat a right word.

Comment: @ bonomo: Your context sounds like software to me. If the *dependencies* are derived from pre-existing classes, call them  *parents*. If the "things depended on" are simply aspects of the software environment that are necessary in order for the lower-level components to function correctly, call them *requirements*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, for derived things there is an established notion of a "prototype" in IT, which isn't my case. Requirements don't look like a good choice either, because there is no urge involved. I tend to believe that Carlo_R suggested the closest match.

Comment: @ bonomo: Much as I respect Carlo's contributions to ELL, he (and I suspect you) are not native speakers of English. In normal usage, an *antecedent* is simply a *thing or event that existed before*. In logic/law that's often stretched to mean *thing or event that logically leads to something happening/being discovered later*, but I think it would be somewhat odd to use it in your context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you are right, I am not a native speaker at all, so this is why I am here asking for help. I suspect that "antecedent" may sound a bit awkward, but so far the notion it conveys matches the best the notion I have in mind. Again, it's not perfect and chances are there simply is no word for it. But I am keep looking and will appreciate if you have something in mind that fits better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I did some research online and this is what I found, please let me know what you think of "precedent": https://www.google.com/search?q=precedent+vs+dependent

Comment: @ bonomo: My own feeling is that you're not helping yourself by failing to give any meaningful context in the question text. Of course, I do realise that if there *is* some suitable "generic" term, the lack of context shouldn't make any difference. You might consider asking this [on ELL](http://english.stackexchange.com/) though - it's possible the right word just hasn't come to mind for me personally, but I think this is probably quite a tricky question, not really of general interest to people learning English.

Comment: ...a *precedent* is normally understood as *an earlier event or action regarded as an example or guide to be considered in subsequent similar circumstances.* But I note it's used in this [Excel for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-trace-precedents-and-dependents-in-excel-20.html) page with what looks like it may be your intended sense. All that suggests to me is there *isn't* an existing word, so people shoe-horn in any remotely credible alternative.

Comment: This has been asked [at EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36033/if-a-person-depends-upon-you-what-are-you-for-him), too. Some time ago, but I think the answers could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two verbs often used to designate the influence exerted over a dependent entity are *govern* and *determine*.

Generally speaking, *govern* tends to be used of formal, logical or legal relationships, while *determine* tends to be used of physical or social causation; but they are pretty interchangeable.

For an adjective, then, I suggest *governing* or *determining/determinant*. For a noun, *determinant* will work, but I don't know of a convenient nominal of *govern*. If you're up to  using a term beyond its normal extension (which is perfectly acceptable with sufficient context), you could use *governor*; or you could revive the obsolete synonym *governant*.

Comment: I really like the fact you mentioned "influence exerted over a dependent entity" this is exactly what it is in my case. Some sort of influence without any more details. I think "determining" is what I am after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If something is dependent on something else then the dependent receives something from the thing it depends on.  You might therefore try:

> [***provider***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provider) : one that provides
>
> [***provide***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provide?show=0&t=1370418937) 2a : to supply or make available (something wanted or needed)
> b : to make something available to
> 3 : to have as a condition

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate StoneyB's answer, and agree that *governor* could be a suitable word choice.

Reading through the comments, though, I would like to suggest a term which is possible preferable: *Controller*. This is a word I've often used in similar software design situations. In this context it has similar meaning to *governor*, but I think would be a more clear term in software development. B depends upon A, the implication in your comments being that A determines some of B's properties and actions. So A would be the *controller* or B, and B dependent upon A.

You really might just stick with *parent* and *child*, the most clear and common software design terminology for similar situations. The child is naturally dependent upon the parent. But if this is unsuitable, I think *controller* ought to meet your needs.